# Dealing with arrays as method results

Tags: java, arrays, methods

So I've got this method:

```
  public static int[] select(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
    int rHeight = StdRandom.uniform(0, maxHeight);
    int rWidth = StdRandom.uniform(0, maxWidth);
    return new int[] {rHeight, rWidth};
  }
```

And I'm not advanced enough to work with it on the right way.
I've got a second method where I want to execute 'select' several times. My idea was to do it with a for-loop like that (in which 'n' is a int):

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
   select(h, w);
}
```

But now I don't know how to save the result from this for-loop in an 1d-array, since I will always get an error when trying to save like that:

```
int[] a = new int[select(h, w)];
```

I'm very aware that this looks very strange and wrong but I just don't know how to do it in the right way and I don't know for what I have to search on google.

Comment: So if you want an array of arrays, you could create an empty array before your loop of size n and set each element in turn in your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way you could do it:

```
int[][] a = new int[n][];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
   a[i] = select(h, w);
}
```

Basically this code creates a 2d array, then in the for loop, adds the result of select to each element of the array.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark it as correct by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: And could you tell me how I can access to this array outside of the for-loop?

Comment: The array is stored as `a` so assuming it isn't in a method, then you can access it anywhere in the class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in a 1D array, if you want to run select multiple times, and each time it returns an array, you'll have to have an array of arrays.  If you are adamant about having a 1D array to store the answers, you'll have to implement a tuple class, although I think you're better off just doing a 2D array the way Sub 6 Resources showed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] combined = new int[n*2];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
       int a[] = select(h, w);
       System.arraycopy(a, 0, combined, i*2, 2);
    }
```

Comment: There is a standard function to copy from one array to another System.arraycopy (read docs about it). so You have combined array size is n*2, because your select(h,w) returns array with 2 elements. Then nothing else just copy from select(h,w) result to the next position in combined array. Is that you would like to have based on what you said, correct?